# xamarin post not making it to api

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Hi my xamarin post is not making it to my rest api.I keep getting "An error occure while sending the request" all my other posts work but just not this one. I have set network permissions as my login and geting data works. any help would be great. below is a code snippet.

```
public async Task<string> PostChecklist(string json)
{
    try
    {
        JToken rootObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        MultipartFormDataContent multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + TokenId);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

        string sFile = (string)rootObject["Answers"]["Signature"];
        //Get file
        if (!File.Exists((string)rootObject["Answers"]["Signature"]))
        {
            return "no signature found";
        }
        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead((string)rootObject["Answers"]["Signature"]);
        StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(fs);
        streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        multipartContent.Add(streamContent, "signature", "signature.png");
        #region Upload images
        JToken jobectImages = rootObject["Images"];

        foreach (var item in jobectImages)
        {
            foreach (var internalitem in item)
            {
                foreach (var imageGroup in internalitem)
                {
                    foreach (JObject image in imageGroup)
                    {
                        JToken tokenName, tokenFileName;

                        image.TryGetValue("FileName", out tokenName);
                        image.TryGetValue("FilePath", out tokenFileName);

                        string FileName = tokenName.ToString();
                        string FilePath = tokenFileName.ToString();

                        //Get file
                        FileStream fs2 = File.OpenRead(FilePath);
                        StreamContent streamContent2 = new StreamContent(fs);
                        streamContent2.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                        multipartContent.Add(streamContent2, FileName, FileName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        var contentJson = new StringContent(json);
        contentJson.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            Name = "JSONString"
        };

        var contentLong = new StringContent("26");
        contentLong.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            Name = "Long"
        };

        var contentLat = new StringContent("96");
        contentLat.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            Name = "Lat"
        };

        multipartContent.Add(contentJson);
        multipartContent.Add(contentLong);
        multipartContent.Add(contentLat);

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(GlobalVariables.url + "/checkurl/answers/v12", multipartContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Information = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JObject jsonOther = JObject.Parse(Information);
            if(((String)jsonOther["status"]) == "success")
            {
                return "";
            }
            else
            {
                return (String)jsonOther["message"];
            }
        }
        else{
            return "Server Error";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return e.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also it works fine on the ios simulator but not on a device is there certain settings that are different for the simulator or the ios

Comment: Could it be this line: `HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();`.  Creating a new HttpClient for every request is known to exhaust the socket pool.

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  Does that exception have an `InnerException`?  What is the URL you are posting to?  This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932064/c-sharp-httpclient-sendasync-throw-an-error-occurred-while-sending-the-request sounds like a similar problem.

Comment: im getting a System.net.Http.HttpRequestException.. Weird thing is it posts fine on simulator but not on a device...and it does post sometimes but 90% of the time it doesnt work

Comment: Can you post the whole exception (including InnerException)?

Answer (score 0):

Cool Looks like there was a problem with one of my MultipartFormDataContent when trying to attach images, if i dont attach an image it does work, so the Url post was breaking. Simulator cant take images so never had the problem.. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

`MultipartFormDataContent` has a bug with how it generates request content based on the order the headers and body are added.

For example

```
StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(fs);
streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
multipartContent.Add(streamContent, "signature", "signature.png");
```

Will cause the content type header to be added before the content disposition header,

```
-----------------------------some boundary value here
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=signature; filename=signature.png
```

which is known to cause issues with how some servers read the body/content of the request

Instead make sure to set the content composition header first and also make sure that the name and file name are wrapped in double quotes before adding it to the multi-part form data content

```
StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(fs);
streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") {
    Name = "\"signature\"",
    Filename = "\"signature.png\""
};
streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
multipartContent.Add(streamContent);
```

The same will need to be done for the other section where images are added

```
//Get file
FileStream fs2 = File.OpenRead(FilePath);
StreamContent streamContent2 = new StreamContent(fs);
streamContent2.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") {
    Name = string.Format("\"{0}\"", FileName),
    Filename = string.Format("\"{0}\"", FileName),
};
streamContent2.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
multipartContent.Add(streamContent2);
```